# Cannot convert value of type 'A' to expected argument type 'A' when using generics

Tags: swift, generics

I'm running into an issue using generics in Swift - I have experience with generics in Java and am working on translating my knowledge as I go. I have a method that takes a generic parameter type, defined in the protocol like so:

```
protocol Board {
    func getPlace<T : Position>(position: T) -> Place
}
```

The idea is that the `Board` can have its own type of `Position`, like an `XYPosition` for a `SquareBoard`, but different types of positions for a hex board.

However, the below playground snippet has a very strange error:

```
/Users/Craig/projects/MyModule/Sources/SquareBoard.swift:16:39: error: cannot convert value of type 'XYPosition' to
 expected argument type 'XYPosition'                                                                                   
        let index = toIndex(position: position)                                                                        
                                      ^~~~~~~~                                                                         
                                               as! XYPosition
```

If I try to force cast the `position`, it gets even weirder:

```
/Users/Craig/projects/MyModule/Sources/SquareBoard.swift:16:48: warning: forced cast of 'XYPosition' to same type h
as no effect                                                                                                           
        let index = toIndex(position: position as! XYPosition)                                                         
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                          

/Users/Craig/projects/MyModule/Sources/SquareBoard.swift:16:48: error: cannot convert value of type 'XYPosition' to
 expected argument type 'XYPosition'                                                                                   
        let index = toIndex(position: position as! XYPosition)                                                         
                                      ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                          
                                                              as! XYPosition
```

Is it redefining the type a second time with a different identity? I can't seem to determine what I'm doing wrong. The issue is reproducible in the below playground:

```
import Cocoa

protocol Position : Equatable {
}

struct XYPosition : Position {
    let x : Int
    let y : Int
}

func ==(lhs: XYPosition, rhs:XYPosition) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

public class Test {

    private func toIndex(position: XYPosition) -> Int {
        return (position.y * 10) + position.x
    }

    func getPlace<XYPosition>(position: XYPosition) -> Int {
        let index = toIndex(position: position as! XYPosition)
        return 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not posting your actual code it's a bit confusing. No clue what getPlace has to do with your issue and I'm unsure what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Either way, I have your playground working, hopefully you can work from there:

```
protocol Position : Equatable {
    var x: Int { get }
    var y: Int { get }
}

struct XYPosition : Position {
    let x : Int
    let y : Int
}

func ==(lhs: XYPosition, rhs:XYPosition) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

public class Test {

    private func toIndex<T: Position>(position: T) -> Int {
        return (position.y * 10) + position.x
    }

    func getPlace<T: Position>(position: T) -> Int {
        let index = toIndex(position: position)
        return index
    }
}
```

First, in your original `getPlace<XYPosition>`, XYPosition is a locally defined type and is not related to your struct, so when you call `as! XYPosition` you're trying to cast it to the local type, not your struct.

Second, I'm guessing you're misunderstanding how to use structs. structs cannot be sub-classed, so you cannot use a struct as a generic. Only a protocol or class. If you're passing a struct, you can just pass the struct itself.